# Matrix formula for the correlation matrix, page 72 from Mathematical Tools for Applied Multivariate Analysis

Tags: correlation, python, covariance, computational-statistics, linear-algebra

### Book information

The book is titled:

*Mathematical Tools for Applied Multivariate Analysis*

By

*Paul E. Green* and *J. Douglas Carroll*

The print that I have is from *1976*

The ISBN number is

`ISBN 0-12-297550-2`

### Text definition

I have the following definition for the correlation matrix:

$$
R = DSD
$$

Where $S$ is the mean corrected cross product matrix, and $D$ is the diagonal
of the cross product, with each element of the diagonal being the reciprocal
of the square root of $S$.

Also, the covariance matrix is defined as $C = \frac{1}{m}S$, where $m$ is
the number of observations.

### Example using values from text, and python

To make this concrete, the following values are taken from the book:

```py
js = '{"y":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":1,"3":4,"4":3,"5":2,"6":5,"7":6,"8":9,"9":13,"10":15,"11":16},"x1":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":2,"3":3,"4":5,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":10,"9":11,"10":11,"11":12},"x2":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":2,"3":2,"4":4,"5":6,"6":5,"7":4,"8":8,"9":7,"10":9,"11":10}}'
A = pd.read_json(js)
m = len(A)
one = np.ones((m, 1))
```

Where `A` is as:

```
|    |   y |   x1 |   x2 |
|---:|----:|-----:|-----:|
|  0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|  1 |   0 |    2 |    1 |
|  2 |   1 |    2 |    2 |
|  3 |   4 |    3 |    2 |
|  4 |   3 |    5 |    4 |
|  5 |   2 |    5 |    6 |
|  6 |   5 |    6 |    5 |
|  7 |   6 |    7 |    4 |
|  8 |   9 |   10 |    8 |
|  9 |  13 |   11 |    7 |
| 10 |  15 |   11 |    9 |
| 11 |  16 |   12 |   10 |
```

This gives us the following for `S`:

```py
S = np.dot( A.T, A) - (1/m) * np.dot( 
                                    (np.dot(A.T, one)),
                                    (np.dot(one.T, A)))
```

Using definition:

$$
S = A'A - \frac{1}{m}(A'1)(1'A)
$$

Looks as:

```
|    |      y |     x1 |      x2 |
|:---|-------:|-------:|--------:|
| y  | 354.25 | 233.25 | 173.25  |
| x1 | 233.25 | 170.25 | 128.25  |
| x2 | 173.25 | 128.25 | 106.917 |
```

Covariance matrix `C`:

```py
C = (1/m) * S
```

Which looks as:

```
|    |       y |      x1 |       x2 |
|:---|--------:|--------:|---------:|
| y  | 29.5208 | 19.4375 | 14.4375  |
| x1 | 19.4375 | 14.1875 | 10.6875  |
| x2 | 14.4375 | 10.6875 |  8.90972 |
```

The diagonal matrix `D` is found using

```py
D = np.diag(1/np.sqrt(C.diagonal()))
```

And looks as:

```
|    |       y |       x1 |       x2 |
|:---|--------:|---------:|---------:|
| y  | 0.18405 | 0        | 0        |
| x1 | 0       | 0.265489 | 0        |
| x2 | 0       | 0        | 0.335018 |
```

Finally, and this is the point of the question, using the definition from the
text `R`, the correlation matrix, is given as

```py
R = np.dot( D, np.dot( S, D))
```

Which gives

```
|    |       y |      x1 |      x2 |
|:---|--------:|--------:|--------:|
| y  | 12      | 11.3974 | 10.6826 |
| x1 | 11.3974 | 12      | 11.407  |
| x2 | 10.6826 | 11.407  | 12      |
```

Which is clearly off by a factor of 12, whereas using the covariance matrix instead gives

```py
R = np.dot( D, np.dot( C, D))
```

```
|    |        y |       x1 |       x2 |
|:---|---------:|---------:|---------:|
| y  | 1        | 0.94978  | 0.890216 |
| x1 | 0.94978  | 1        | 0.950585 |
| x2 | 0.890216 | 0.950585 | 1        |
```

Which is how I would expect the correlation matrix to look.

### My question

Should I just be using the covariance for the computation of the correlation
matrix? This seems like it should be the case, given the above computations.

The code is provided to, hopefully, make things clearer. I don't require that
the answer uses Python, matrix computations are fine.

### All code

```py
js = '{"y":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":1,"3":4,"4":3,"5":2,"6":5,"7":6,"8":9,"9":13,"10":15,"11":16},"x1":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":2,"3":3,"4":5,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":10,"9":11,"10":11,"11":12},"x2":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":2,"3":2,"4":4,"5":6,"6":5,"7":4,"8":8,"9":7,"10":9,"11":10}}'
A = pd.read_json(js)
m = len(A)
one = np.ones((m, 1))

S = np.dot( A.T, A) - (1/m) * np.dot( ( np.dot ( A.T, one )  )  , ( np.dot( one.T , A ) ))

C = (1/m) * S

# this doesn't look right, but is what's used in the text
R = np.dot( D, np.dot( S, D))
# this looks correct
R = np.dot( D, np.dot( C, D))
```

## Edit - photos of text for context

In case the above seems a bit vague, I'd added some photos of the original text here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your "$S$" is *not* the **mean** sum of products matrix: it is the **total** sum of products matrix. That's why your result is off by a constant multiple.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I've implemented the formulas that are in the text (S is defined at the top of page 71). Also, S is explained as "mean corrected" rather than "mean sum" as you state. I will add photo's to the post of the text source

Comment: @whuber I have added images, hopefully they make it more clear, thank you

Comment: Permit me to repeat: the "mean corrected cross product matrix" to which you refer at the outset is *not* what is shown as $S$ in the images.  Look at the top line!  It states $S$ is the "sum of squares and cross products" matrix: there is no "mean" in the description.

Comment: I'm not following your explanation, it says mean corrected in their description as well, my confusion remains

Comment: I don't find book titles as distinctive or as searchable as author names. The allusion appears to be to a 1997 book by J. Douglas Carroll and Paul E. Green -- or perhaps to an earlier edition with authors' names reversed. You tell us, please.

Comment: @NickCox updated